# ELMAH not displaying all error logs from SQL Server in elmah.axd

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, elmah

I setup Elmah to log errors to SQL Server, the web application is logging all errors to the database but not all are getting displayed in `elmah.axd`.

Some of the errors that are missing are:

- `System.Web.HttpUnhandledException`

  > _shutDownMessage=HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown  HostingEnvironment caused shutdown    _shutDownStack=
  >   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
  >   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
  >   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownInternal()....
- `System.Web.HttpException`

  > Session state is not available in this context.
- > _shutDownMessage=IIS configuration change  HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown  HostingEnvironment caused shutdown  CONFIG change    _shutDownStack=
  >   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
  >   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace() .....

See attached screenshots.

How do I make all errors in the database appear in `elmah.axd`?

When I was saving the error in the file system it was all fine but not when I moved to SQL Server.

Thanks!

[image: error logs in the database]

[image: error logs in showing in elmah.axd]

Comment: It looks like you may be running with the in-memory or file error logger on the bottom screenshot. Try clicking one of the errors in the list on elmah.axd, copy the error id and search for the error id in SQL Server. Is it there?

Answer (score 5):

If I may humbly build on what the chief architect Atif said, in your **Web.config**, it's this section:

```
<elmah>
  <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="foo" />
</elmah>
```

Set it to:

```
<elmah>
  <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="foo" applicationName="*" />
</elmah>
```

This will show *all* database error records rather than only the records that match the application name Elmah is running under.  If the **applicationName** attribute is not provided, it's only going to return records that match the IIS assigned identifier, e.g.- "/LM/W3SVC/10/ROOT".

This is really useful if you have an application that is used purely for viewing logged Elmah errors across all applications in an environment.

I <3 Elmah!

Comment: I'm getting `Error Log for * on XXX` and `No errors found.`. The star is not recognized as a wildcard, is there a setting for that in web.config?

Comment: Ah, it looks like I may have missed providing a key change to the Elmah stored procedures: [ELMAH_GetErrorsXml] and [ELMAH_GetErrorXml].  In those sprocs, try changing all instances in the WHERE clause of: `[Application] = @Application` to: `(@Application = '*' OR ([Application] = @Application))`.  This way, the app that's using `applicationName="*"` as its Elmah application name will return all records and all the other applications will still return records specific to their `applicationName="MyAppName"`.  Let me know if that helped.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I don't want to touch Elmah's code, so I opted for using the same `applicationName` for all.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you have different application names (see the `Application` column in your screenshot) and `SqlErrorLog` will only display errors belonging to the application name you configured in your `web.config` (and in absence of one, ELMAH will default to an identifier assigned by IIS, like `/LM/W3SVC/10/ROOT`). This is by-design as it permits you to use one back-end database for multiple web applications. It's always best to configure a stable and logical application name. If all those errors are for the same application, you can run an `UPDATE` statement on the table to set the `Application` column to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

I used sqlErrorLog, just set ApplicationName for sqlErrorLog:
Code:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
var sqlErrorLog = new Elmah.SqlErrorLog(connectionString);

var controller = executedContext.Controller as Controller;
if (controller != null)
    sqlErrorLog.ApplicationName = controller.Request.ServerVariables["APPL_MD_PATH"];
var errorId = sqlErrorLog.Log(error);
```

result image:
[image]